# Modify variable from MainActivity in my Service class then update the TextView with variable

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to modify a variable (Happiness) from my MainActivity.class SharedPrefs whenever the service is ran. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Please find below my code, My result ends up with happiness = -1 which is because of the prefEditor.putInt I understand but unsure how to proceed modifying and returning value.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int Health = 100;
private static final int Happiness = 100;
int Hunger = 0;
int Level = 1;
EditText happiness_display,
         health_display,
         hunger_display,
         level_display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFS",
                                                  MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
        prefEditor.putInt("HAPPINESS", Happiness);
        prefEditor.commit();

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.pet_display);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/renamon.gif");
        myWebView.setInitialScale(10000);


        ShowToast();

        TextView happiness = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.happiness_display);
        happiness.setText(Integer.toString(Happiness));

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, chronos.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Start every 30 seconds
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent); 
    }


    private void ShowToast() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast method invoked from on create " + Happiness, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

public class chronos extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFS",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
        prefEditor.putInt("HAPPINESS",  - 1);
        prefEditor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Chronos running" + settings.getInt("HAPPINESS", 0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated or a point in the right direction if my methodology is wrong (probably is :P)

It is probably my incoherence but I'm basically wanting to modify the value of Happiness, Health etc.. every time the service is ran, Like a game loop but for virtual pets.

Example code in my IntentService

```
happiness = happiness - 1;
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
        prefEditor.putInt("HAPPINESS", happiness);
        prefEditor.commit();
```

I just want everytime the service runs for it to subtract a set amount from some variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

First of all, use `IntentService` instead of `Service` as it blocks the UI thread.

Like this

```
public class chronos extends IntentService {

    int happiness;
    public chronos() {
        super("chronos");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFS",
                MODE_PRIVATE);

            happiness = settings.getInt("HAPPINESS",0) - 1;

            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
            prefEditor.putInt("HAPPINESS",happiness);
            prefEditor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Chronos running" + settings.getInt("HAPPINESS", 0),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

If you want to update `TextView` value's of MainActivity from Service, need to use [BroadcastReceiver](http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/)

Comment: That would not modify the value of the Happiness variable which is stored SharedPref Key "HAPPINESS" though? The toast message I should clarify is for debugging, for example the value it displays is "-1" rather than the new value of happiness which should be "99" (100-1)

Comment: It can't perform arithmetic operation, you need to do it separately and then store the result back to Shared Preferences.

Comment: Would you happen to be able to explain how to do the actual arithmetic please?

Comment: Every time services run it should update your views from Main Activity?? can you tell what kind of operation you are going to do in service?

Comment: Mainly subtracting from the variables set in the MainActivity for example every half an hour subtract -1 from happiness and 3 from hunger etc..

Comment: Updated my question I want to modify the variables from my MainActivity everytime the service runs, that is all, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you and thank you for the heads up about the broadcast receiver :)